# Flask-Sijax callbacks are "working outside of request context"

Tags: python, flask, sijax

While inside a callback function, I lose the ability to access flask.session, flask.g, or functions such as url_for(). They all throw an error saying that I'm "working outside of request context".

```
Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\site-packages\sijax\response\streaming.py", line 136, in _process_call_chain
    for string in generator:
  File "C:\Python27\site-packages\sijax\response\streaming.py", line 109, in _process_callback
    response = self._perform_handler_call(callback, args)
  File "C:\Python27\site-packages\sijax\response\base.py", line 258, in _perform_handler_call
    return callback(self, *args)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Code\Python 2.7\FlaskTesting\testpage.py", line 18, in myformhandler
    sql_session = flask.g.sql_session
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 336, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 295, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 19, in _lookup_object
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of request context')
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
192.168.1.141 - - [20/Jun/2012 16:33:04] "POST /testpage HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I've been unable to find out how to get around this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

- Python v2.7
- Flask v0.8
- Flask-Sijax v0.3

Comment: Paste your code, even if you have already solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a try with stream_with_context. The code example copied from http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/streaming/#streaming-with-context

```
from flask import stream_with_context, request, Response

@app.route('/stream')
def streamed_response():
    def generate():
        yield 'Hello '
        yield request.args['name']
        yield '!'
    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted your code, but try wrapping your code like this:

```
with app.app_context():
    # do stuff...
```

or maybe this:

```
with app.test_request_context():
    # do stuff...
```